# I cannot flip one face

Tags: faces

I've imported image as plane with the addon. Then I've extruded that plane into the cube form. The problem is that I can flip only all faces instead of one selected. When I'm selecting that one face I want to flip, and then I'm trying to flip it outside, it doesn't do anything. One face is always directed inside, while the rest outside. I also tried to apply scale etc. and it doesn't change anything. It's simple cube maded from the plane. There's no faces inside, simple 8 vertice cube. I've tried to recalculate all faces inside, outside, and it doesn't do anything. The cube is a painting, all faces are with default white material, and one face should have the painting image. How can I fix that one face?

[image]

There's no blue faces, because I've changed them in theme to be transparent, so I can always see wrong faces by default.

Comment: Hello, do you mean that you're trying to flip the normals? If you don't display the face orientations, you won't see if the face are flipped or not, could you please tell a bit more or share your file?

Comment: Im trying to flip that one red face with the painting on it. This is simple painting canvas model (cuboid), where everyting should be white, except one face with painting. But I think it's an addon bug

Comment: what do you mean by flipping? Generally the word is used for faces orientation